# Unable to get the Historical data from API Interactive brokers

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, interactive, interactive-brokers

I'm trying to access Historical data of API Interactive brokers but I can't get the data.

My code looks like this:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import datetime


class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        # Get the current year and month
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        year = now.year
        month = now.month

        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "ES"
        contract.secType = "FUT"
        contract.exchange = "GLOBEX"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.localSymbol = "ESZ7"  # Set the local symbol

        self.reqHistoricalData(orderId, contract, "", "1 D", "1 hour", "TRADES", 0, 1, True, [])

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f"Historical data: {bar}")

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
        print("End of HistoricalData")
        print(f"Start: {start}, End: {end}")


app = TestApp()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 1)
app.run()
```

And I get the following error:

**ERROR 1 200 No security definition has been found for the request**

I have real times running on the futures contracts, do I need to activate another authorization in addition?

I would be very grateful if someone here could help me solve the problem.

Comment: Do you subscription to mini futures ? , it is add on service than your normal  data subscription.

Comment: Yes, I bought the CME of mini futures

Comment: may be try contract.exchange = "CME"

Comment: Thank you very much bro, it worked!!!
Could you please tell me what CME means?

Comment: Its exchange that provides quotes for futures. Known as Chicago Mercantile Exchange

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

1. I had to change contract.exchange = "GLOBEX" to contract.exchange = "CME"
2. I had to add the following line:
   contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "202303"

Comment: Yes the exchange name change happened in Nov/Dec depending on the contract